# Query values for more than one entity in a single datomic query (Roam Alpha Api)

Tags: datomic, datalog

I'd like to in a single datomic/datalog query get output relating to multiple entities

E.g.

In my db (querying Roam graph via RoamAlphaApi) for one value (`"YjpbFUsTx"`) I can do this:

`[:find ?e ?stri :where [?e :block/uid "YjpbFUsTx"][?e :block/string ?stri]]`

gives me

| ?e | ?stri |
| --- | --- |
| 420 | Hello |

But I want to pass on two values `"YjpbFUsTx"` and `"TgpgOssBM"`

to give me

| ?e | ?stri |
| --- | --- |
| 420 | Hello |
| 624 | Perfect |

How do I do that?

I've tried several variations but none give any output.

Useful reference: https://www.zsolt.blog/2021/01/Roam-Data-Structure-Query.html .

Answer (score 0):

You can pass collections into a parametrized query.
Have a look in the documentation: https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/best-practices.html#collections-as-inputs

```clj
(d/q 
 '[:find ?e ?stri
   :in $ [?uid ...]
   :where 
   [?e :block/uid ?uid]
   [?e :block/string ?stri]]
 db ["YjpbFUsTx" "TgpgOssBM"])

; =>
#{[420 "Hello"][624 "Perfect"]}
```

---

On another note:
I suspect, your `:block/uid` is a unique identifier?
If you have `:db/unique :db.unique/identity` set for the attribute, you should use `d/pull-many` in this situation:

```clj
(d/pull-many db 
  [:db/id :block/string] 
  [[:block/uid "YjpbFUsTx"] [:block/uid "TgpgOssBM"]])

; =>
[{:db/id 420
  :block/string "Hello"}
 {:db/id 624
  :block/string "Perfect"}]
```